# Выбор базы данных для новичка в Python и БД

Tags: mysql, python, база-данных, postgresql, python-3.x

Слышал много про разные типы базы данных от кажется SimpleBD (в одном файле), до MySQL, Postgresql. Как они работают (в целом со стороны) я понимаю на уровне пользователя. Но вот язык общения с ними (sql запросы для меня почти темный лес). Хочется иметь несложную в настройке\администрировании БД, к которой легко писать запросы из python скрипта, получать данные, загружать данные. Все это нужно для обучения, личного\рабочего использования, не направленного на масс-use (высоко-нагруженные сайты).

Вопрос: Поделитесь опытом с какой из БД и библиотекой в python проще всего взаимодействовать с данными для новичка, что бы не вылазило по 10-20 ошибок, из за сложного синтаксиса запросов в котором нужно очень долго разбираться. Правильно ли я понимаю что самая распространенная это MySQL и под нее можно найти больше примеров\видео уроков?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Собственно всё, что нужно знать для работы с SQLite:

```
### SQL QUERIES ###
selAll = "SELECT * FROM tasks"

createCommand = """ # Создать таблицу
    CREATE TABLE tasks (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        'Задача' NVARCHAR(1000),
        'Подзадача' NVARCHAR(1000),
        'Сотрудник' NVARCHAR(50),
        'Дата' DATE,
        'Статус' NVARCHAR(200),
        'Коммент' NVARCHAR(1000),
        'Тек статус' NVARCHAR(30),
        'Осталось' INTEGER
    );"""

searchText = """ # Искать в таблице
    SELECT * FROM tasks 
     WHERE Задача like "%{kword}%" 
         OR Подзадача like "%{kword}%" 
         OR Сотрудник like "%{kword}%";""" 

insertText = """ # Внести новые данные в таблицу
    INSERT INTO tasks (ID, 'Задача', 'Подзадача', 'Сотрудник', 'Дата',
        'Статус', 'Коммент', 'Тек статус'
    )
    VALUES (NULL, "{tsk}", "{stsk}", "{prsn}", "{dt}", "{stts}", "{cmt}", "{crsts}"
    );"""

deleteText = "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE ID = {key}" # Удалить некоторые данные

updateText = """UPDATE tasks # Отредактировать данные
    SET 'Задача'="{tsk}", 'Подзадача'="{stsk}", 'Сотрудник'="{prsn}", 'Дата'="{dt}", 
    'Статус'="{stts}", 'Коммент'="{cmt}", 'Тек статус'="{crsts}"
    WHERE ID = {key};"""
```

Использование в Питоне.
Создание таблицы:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(createCommand)
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    pass
```

Вставка данных из словаря (newRecordDict) в таблицу:

```
insertCommand = insertText.format(
        tsk=newRecordDict["Задача"],
        stsk=newRecordDict["Подзадача"],
        prsn=newRecordDict["Сотрудник"],
        dt=newRecordDict["Дата"],
        stts=newRecordDict["Статус"],
        cmt=newRecordDict["Коммент"],
        crsts=newRecordDict["Тек статус"]
    )
    cursor.execute(insertCommand)
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 6):

Самый простой для вас путь, это использовать [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/). Хорошая система для новичка, не требует познаний в администрировании, проста для установки и использования. SQL знать нужно в любом случае, так что запаситесь терпением и изучайте по мере движения вперёд. Даже переехав под ORM Джанги, знания кухни SQL вам пригодятся.

MySQL одна из распространённых баз, равно как и Postgresql и уроков для этих баз множество. Выбор базы для проекта определяется требованием к надежности хранения, скорости работы и т.д. Сейчас забивать голову этим смысла нет. Постепенно понимание что нужно придёт само.

Comment: Задал вопрос - думаю поспешил, с новой базой думаю будет сложнее разобраться. Вроде как есть какие то представления об MySQL  и небольшой совсем опыт, и даже на Python небольшой скрипт и библиотека есть для взаимодействия. Приму как подошедший ответ! Спасибо